# Adding conditional to Store "Hurry! Only x items left!!"

Tags: expresso-store

I'm setting up an online apparel store and would like to set up a conditional that will check the item count in a particular sku number and output something like this "Hurry, only 9 left!!" when the count is equal or less than say 10.

I tried

```
{if store_product_stock <= 10}
<p>Hurry, only <em><span class="store_product_stock"></span></em> left!</p>
{/if}
```

But that doesn't work. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

According to the store docs your can use `total_stock` for that.

Example:

```
{if total_stock > 0} In Stock {if:else} Out of Stock {/if}
```

https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#total_stock

Comment: Thank you, but that only applies to the item as a whole. I have different skus for a single product (tshirts with different sizes)